# Wordpress CSS img Float Left Issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get three images to float left of each other (so they are on a horizontal line) but am having issues. Can't seem to find what is causing it and would like to have another set of eyes see if I am missing anything.

I am building the site in Wordpress.

You can see the exact example I am working on here, trying to get the three images on that page to float left: http://goldenleafdesigns.com/about_trees/services/

I have tied many things but none have fixed it.... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're floating the images. You need to float their parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the CSS-rules you need to change:

```
.shortcode1-4 {
     width: 100%;
}
```

And: try to get rid of br-tags...

Comment: Your welcome. Can you please check the right answer or like so that I get some of those awesome StackOverflow points? :D

Answer (score 0):

parent of image `<artical>` has `23%` width, so they won't appear in horizontal line
 untill you set width to `100%` or whatever required to you

```
.shortcode1-4 {
    width : 100%
}
```